# Prevent navigation away from dialog in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I'm new to jQuery mobile and am trying to build a PhoneGap app using jQuery mobile.

I'm a bit stuck with the following issue.

I have a login dialog as a form that I want to show the user if they need to log in.  I don't want them to be able to navigate away from this login form until they have signed in.  I've removed all links in the dialog but the hardware back button still works.

I've tried the following:

Copy code

```
function onDocumentReady() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);

    $("#loginDialog").on("pagebeforehide",
        function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            console.info('in pagebeforehide');
        }

    );
}
```

This is not working though.  The code gets called (I've added a breakpoint) but the call to event.preventDefault() is not stopping the navigation away from the page.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I have told in many answers PhoneGap and Android back button messes up very much.

You can disable Android back button as below

```
$(function(){
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
})

// PhoneGap is loaded and it is now safe to call PhoneGap methods
function onDeviceReady() {
    // Register the event listener
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}

// Handle the back button
function onBackKeyDown() {
    console.log("back button not fired");
}
```

Comment: This worked (which is impressive) but I'd rather find a solution that doesn't actually disable the back button since the user may still want to use the back button in other scenarios.  I tried to disable the back button only when on the login page and re-enable it when going to other pages but this didn't work consistently which was strange. I'm going to upvote your answer since it is a solution but not the ideal one.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Figured out what I was doing wrong and can now do it consistently.  Going to accept your answer since it was the one that helped me but will edit it to include complete answer.  Thanks again!

Comment: Great. Glad it helped you out.

Answer (score 0):

preventDefault will prevent the default action for say an anchor tag. If you want to disable the back button try this:

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
    window.history.forward();
    function noBack() { window.history.forward(); }
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY onload="noBack();"
    onpageshow="if (event.persisted) noBack();" onunload="">
```

Comment: This didn't work.  Not sure if I was adding the code in the correct place.  I added the window.history.forward() statement in place of event.preventDefault in my code (I'm using SPA)